# Ubuntu 16.04 - Force the use of AMD graphics

Tags: 16.04, graphics, radeon

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 (fresh install). I have a Hybrid AMD/intel graphic card. Ubuntu uses intel card as default.

How can I force ubuntu to use the AMD radeon R6 M265 with open source drivers?

I do not care to switch between cards, I just want to use AMD. I cannot disable the intel card in bios.

Thank you!

Comment: AMD support in 16.04 is broken.  I also have a hybrid AMD/Intel card in my laptop, and while the AMD card is powered, I've never been able to make it active.  You could try `echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` to see if it works on yours.  But I've never been able to get my 7960 to come up.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to force it to use AMD with open source drivers, but you're probably going to have worse performance than you will just using Intel.

The AMD open source drivers have no support for newer OpenGL (or CL, can't remember) versions, which cripples some video playback and kills many graphically intense applications. It also puts Minecraft out of the question.

Even though in normal cases, integrated graphics are less powerful than discrete (even AMD), the lack of an adequate driver for AMD cards in Linux means AMD cards will probably have worse performance than Intel in most cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I noticed that, using intel graphics, battery life has doubled... And that's good! Only virtual machines have poor graphic performance because my intel card does not have 3D features...

Comment: Intel has 3D features. You need to enable it in VM settings and install add-ons.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Who told you that. You answer is all wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 told me which?

Comment: @Pilot6 for the first paragraph, I have AMD graphics with 16.04 and the performance is not great. For the second, I've seen countless questions about gaming with 16.04 and AMD and how games always report that the OpenGL version is too low. For the third, that's true in my experience.

Comment: @Pilot6 also this article that states that OpenGL 4.3 doesn't work http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04